# Why using "/=" fail in this case?

Tags: python

Can someone help to explain me why the following "/=" does not  work?

```
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 3, 4],
              [1, 6, 4]])

x_norm = np.linalg.norm(x, ord = 2, axis = 1, keepdims = True)
x /= x_norm


print(x_norm)
print(x_norm.shape)
print(x)
```

To make code work, I have to replace /= by a standard "x = x/x_norm"
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

There is datatype mismatch, tell the datatype as `float64`

```py
import numpy as np

x = np.array([[0, 3, 4],
              [1, 6, 4]], dtype='float64')

x_norm = np.linalg.norm(x, ord = 2, axis = 1, keepdims = True)

x /= x_norm


print(x_norm)
print(x_norm.shape)
print(x)
```

Also `x = x/x_norm` is not exactly same, you are essentially reassigning `x` with `x/x_norm` that is why python does not give an error.